# Passing JS number array to emscripten C++ without reinterpret_cast

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I have large number arrays in JS which I want to pass to C++ for processing.
IMHO the most efficient way is to let JS write directly to the C++ heap and pass a pointer as argument within a direct call, like:

```
var size = 4096,
    BPE = Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    buf = Module._malloc(size * BPE),
    numbers = Module.HEAPF64.subarray(buf / BPE, buf / BPE + size),
    i;
// Populate the array and process the numbers:
parseResult(result, numbers);
Module.myFunc(buf, size);
```

The C++ functions to process the numbers look like:

```
void origFunc(double *buf, unsigned int size) {
  // process the data ...
}
void myFunc(uintptr_t bufAddr, unsigned int size) {
  origFunc(reinterpret_cast<double*>(bufAddr), size);
}
```

That works as expected but I wonder if there is any chance to call the **`origFunc`** directly from Javascript to get rid of **`myFunc`** and the *ugly* **`reinterpret_cast`**.
When I tried to bind origFunc via:

```
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(test) {
  function("origFunc", &origFunc, emscripten::allow_raw_pointers());
}
```

... and call it directly:

```
Module.origFunc(buf, size);
```

I get the error:
*Uncaught UnboundTypeError: Cannot call origFunc due to unbound types: Pd*

Is this a general restriction of emscripten or is there a "less dirty" solutions than the `reinterpret_cast` work around?

Comment: I don't know emscripten well, but it looks like you modify the location of the allocated array `buf / BPE` before passing it into the function. I suspect that needs to be `buf`. And possibly the  size argument for the function should be just `size * BPE`.

Comment: The error speaks of type `Pd` but the code snippets show no `Pd`, what is `Pd`?

Comment: IMHO "Pd" comes from emscripten and stays for "Pointer double"

Comment: The buf computation is correct, _malloc() returns a byte address, but HEAPF64.subArray() is segmented into 8 bytes for each double (F64) element

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I can help (past the previous comments).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `static_cast` if you

- specify that function takes a `void *` rather than a `uintptr_t`;
- don't use `EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS`, but use the `EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE` + `cwrap` / `ccall` way of communicating JS->C++ . For some reason, the `EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS` way resulted in a `getTypeName is not defined` exception when I tried it.

So the function looks like:

```
extern "C" int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE myFunc(void *bufAddr, unsigned int size) {
  origFunc(static_cast<double *>(bufAddr), size);
  return 0;
}
```

which can be called from Javascript by

```
Module.ccall('myFunc', 'number' ['number', 'number'], [buf, size]);
```